# Get values from push notification

Tags: swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented firebase push notification in my app. Now I'm receiving notification details like this,

```
[AnyHashable("gcm.notification.details"): +12345, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.type"): video, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.group_name"): test, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:1538469426956356%def3521bdef3521b, AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("aps"): {
alert = "+12345";
```

}]

I have tried to get the value, but I'm getting it nil like this,

```
let notification = userInfo["type"] as? [AnyHashable: Any]
    print(notification)
```

How can I get all the values from the notification?

Comment: There doesn't  seem to be a `type` key in your notification's payload.

Comment: i have also tried with this gcm.notification.type but get nil value. @DávidPásztor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're parsing the payload incorrectly. Why would you expect the value of the key `gcm.notification.type` to be another `Dictionary`? It is clearly a single value of type `String`.

```
let notificationType = userInfo["gcm.notification.type"] as? String
```

Comment: how can we handle option key?
i.e userInfo["AnyKey"] & it's optional it could be there or not.